# mirrors.iuscommunity.org not available?

Tags: yum, repository

When trying to use yum to install a package on CENTOS 7, 'yum install' failed.

Here is the error message:

```
yum install mariadb101u-server

 Loaded plugins: fastestmirror Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile epel/x86_64/metalink Could not retrieve mirrorlist
 https://mirrors.iuscommunity.org/mirrorlist?repo=ius-centos7&arch=x86_64&protocol=http
 error was 14: curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: mirrors.iuscommunity.org; Unknown error"
 One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown), and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue.
```

It appears that mirrors.iuscommunity.org is not available. Also when I try to

```
ping mirrors.iuscommunity.org
```

or use `nslookup` that does not work.

Any thoughts?

(yes, I have a working network :-) )

Comment: Seems they moved part of their infra , see this : https://github.com/iusrepo/infrastructure/issues/14

Comment: That link states to run:
yum update ius-release
yum clean all

But that doesn't work if the repository is not correct...

Comment: On that page it says you can download and install it manually:
https://repo.ius.io/ius-release-el7.rpm

Downloaded it and tried to install it but yum gives an error message: "does not update installed package".

Answer (score 2):

Solved it.
It turns out that my puppet master has an old ius.repo file which was uploaded to the puppet client every time I ran "puppet agent -t".
That old ius.repo file was then used and that caused the issues.